# Examples of inner forms

Tags: algebraic-groups, examples-counterexamples

Let $G$ and $G′$ be two linear algebraic groups over a field $F$. From what I understand, $G$ is called an inner form of $G′$ if $G$ and $G′$ are isomorphic over a the (or an?) algebraic closure of $F$.

I would like to see an example of this. Are there, for example, a simple example with matrices of this?

Comment: No: $SU(n)$ and $SL_n({\mathbb R})$ are OUTER forms of each other;one says they are inner forms if they are Galois twists of each other, with the twists lying in $Int(G)$ where $Int (G)$ are the group of inner automorphisms of the group $G$ regarded as an algebraic group over the alg closure of $F$.

Comment: by twists i mean a one cocycle of the galois group of $F$, with values in $Int G$

Comment: @Venkataramana: I am not sure that I understand your comment. So there are no examples of this?

Comment: The comment was to say that if $G,G'$ are isomorphic over the alg closure of $F$, they need not be inner forms. Examples of inner forms: $SL_1(D)$ for a quaternionic algebra over $F$ and $SL_2$ are inner forms. $SU(2,1)$ and $SU(3)$ are inner forms.

Comment: @Venkataramana: Ok, thanks. I must have the definition of inner form wrong then. Would you write and answer then with the definition and include your examples? (That way I can accept an answer.)